# How do you calculate optimal exercise boundary?

Tags: options, american-options

In the Broadie-Glasserman article there is a picture of simulated paths and Optimal Exercise region. How did they find this optimal exercise boudary?

[image]

Comment: There is no explicit formula, you have to rely on numerical methods. (Solving the free boundary PDE, or an integral equation).  There is a lot known about the Optimal Exercise curve, but no closed form solution. What do you want to do?